# Vue.js3 - Reaonly on nested object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

Is there any way using the new Vue.js [Reactivity API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/reactivity-api.html) to bind an object key to an existing Ref value as readonly?

**Example**.

```
setup() {
  const input = ref({
    firstName: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@so.com'
  })

  const args = {
    postID: 32,
    email: readonly(input.value.email)
  }

  return { input, args }
}
```

This doesn't work.
`args.email` doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@boussadjra-brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim) pointed out, **readonly** can't be used for nested fields.
Only workaround without copying the whole object might be using **computed** then.

```
const args = computed(() => {
  return {
    post_id: 32,
    email: input.value.email,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`Readonly` accepts a property created using `ref` or `reactive` not a nested field in that property in order to be reactive:

```
 const input = ref({
    firstName: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@so.com'
  })

  const args =readonly(input)
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use readonly for the whole object in this situation. Using computed might be a better solution then I guess.

Comment: I just mentioned that, in this case readonly looks useless, it's recommended to use computed as you did since it's reactive and immutable